# How do I calculate speed from a gpx file if the speed tag itself is not given?

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, gpx

For example, I might have some information like this:

```
<trkpt lat="-33.8161780" lon="150.8710320">
 <ele>73.0</ele>
 <time>2017-07-08T22:05:45Z</time>
 <extensions>
  <power>0</power>
  <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
    <gpxtpx:atemp>7</gpxtpx:atemp>
    <gpxtpx:hr>115</gpxtpx:hr>
    <gpxtpx:cad>27</gpxtpx:cad>
  </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
 </extensions>
</trkpt>
```

How would I calculate speed from this info? I've used the python etree module to parse the file, and have all the info in a pandas database.

It was mentioned that I should probably instead show the pandas dataframe. It looks something like this:

```
                     longitude   latitude   ele   temp
time                
2017-07-08 22:05:45 150.8710320 -33.8161780 73.0    7
2017-07-08 22:05:46 150.8710350 -33.8161500 73.0    7
2017-07-08 22:05:47 150.8710440 -33.8161170 73.0    7
2017-07-08 22:05:48 150.8710540 -33.8160820 73.0    7
2017-07-08 22:05:49 150.8710690 -33.8160430 73.0    7
```

and so on.

Comment: Given *two* time-space coordinates, you could compute an average speed.

Comment: Since you've already parsed the XML into a Pandas DataFrame, it might be easier for us to show the computation if you post the DataFrame as a starting point.

Comment: You would just take two adjacent datapoints, compute the distance between them, and then divide by the time difference, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`speed` equals `distance / time`. The `longitude` and `latitude` presumably represent locations on the surface of the Earth. If we accept a sphere of radius 6371 km as an approximation of the Earth, then we can easily translate the `longitude` and `latitude` into `xyz`-coordinates:

```
r = 6371000 # meters
df['theta'] = np.deg2rad(df['longitude'])
df['phi'] = np.deg2rad(df['latitude'])
df['x'] = r*np.cos(df['theta'])*np.sin(df['phi'])
df['y'] = r*np.sin(df['theta'])*np.sin(df['phi'])
df['z'] = r*np.cos(df['phi'])
```

Now it is not hard to compute distances between consecutive points:

```
df['x2'] = df['x'].shift()
df['y2'] = df['y'].shift()
df['z2'] = df['z'].shift()
df['distance'] = np.sqrt((df['x2']-df['x'])**2 + (df['y2']-df['y'])**2 + (df['z2']-df['z'])**2)
```

However, this is a chord length -- the straight-line distance between two points on the surface of the sphere. If the points are far apart, the chord would be burrowing through the surface of the Earth.  Presumably the motion is on the surface of the Earth. So a more accurate calculation for distance would use the [arclength](http://www.mathopenref.com/arclength.html):

```
df['central angle'] = np.arccos((df['x']*df['x2'] + df['y']*df['y2'] + df['z']*df['z2'])/r**2)
df['arclength'] = df['central angle']*r
```

The central angle is using the [dot product formula](http://mathinsight.org/dot_product_formula_components).

Having computed the arclength (distance), we must now also compute the `time` interval between consecutive observations (i.e. rows of the DataFrame):

```
df['time'] = (df.index.to_series().diff() / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1))
```

So using `speed = distance / time`:

```
df['speed'] = df['arclength'] / df['time']  # in meters/second
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ele': [73.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.0], 'latitude': [-33.816178, -33.81615, -33.816117, -33.816082, -33.816043], 'longitude': [150.871032, 150.871035, 150.87104399999998, 150.87105400000002, 150.871069], 'temp': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7], 'time': ['2017-07-08 22:05:45', '2017-07-08 22:05:46', '2017-07-08 22:05:47', '2017-07-08 22:05:48', '2017-07-08 22:05:49']})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')
columns = df.columns.tolist()

r = 6371000 # radius of the Earth in meters
df['theta'] = np.deg2rad(df['longitude'])
df['phi'] = np.deg2rad(df['latitude'])
df['x'] = r*np.cos(df['theta'])*np.sin(df['phi'])
df['y'] = r*np.sin(df['theta'])*np.sin(df['phi'])
df['z'] = r*np.cos(df['phi'])
df['x2'] = df['x'].shift()
df['y2'] = df['y'].shift()
df['z2'] = df['z'].shift()
df['distance'] = np.sqrt((df['x2']-df['x'])**2 + (df['y2']-df['y'])**2 + (df['z2']-df['z'])**2)

df['central angle'] = np.arccos((df['x']*df['x2'] + df['y']*df['y2'] + df['z']*df['z2'])/r**2)
df['arclength'] = df['central angle']*r

df['time'] = (df.index.to_series().diff() / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1))
df['speed'] = df['arclength'] / df['time']  # in meters/second
df = df[columns + ['speed']]
print(df)
```

yields

```
                      ele   latitude   longitude  temp     speed
time                                                            
2017-07-08 22:05:45  73.0 -33.816178  150.871032     7       NaN
2017-07-08 22:05:46  73.0 -33.816150  150.871035     7  3.119892
2017-07-08 22:05:47  73.0 -33.816117  150.871044     7  3.712201
2017-07-08 22:05:48  73.0 -33.816082  150.871054     7  3.940673
2017-07-08 22:05:49  73.0 -33.816043  150.871069     7  4.433590
```

If you comment out

```
df = df[columns + ['speed']]
```

and re-run the script, you'll see all the intermediate calculations.  You'll
notice that `df['distance']` is quite close to `df['arclength']`. Since the
points are not very far apart on the surface of the Earth, the chord length is a
good approximation of the arclength. So for the data you posted

```
df['speed'] = df['distance'] / df['time']
```

would have worked just as well. However, the `arclength` calculation is a bit
more robust since it will give a more accurate value if the points are far
apart.

Comment: calculate x2,y2,z2 before distance, use gpx_converter to read gpx file and plotly to display, otherwise works great